# Unable to print after exporting to PDF on Adobe Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been using Adobe Photoshop CC for creating banners and material for printing but recently a friend tried to print something I made and he said he was unable to print it due to an error.

This is how I create PDF files for printing: 
File > Automate > PDF Presentation

And these are images with the exact settings I used for printing
http://postimg.org/gallery/30sraluoe/

What am I doing wrong? This never happened before so I'm kinda confused and I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could be because of file size. If then merge all layers into one and export with 200dpi.

Comment: Wouldn't that reduce drastically the document quality? I'll try that though, thanks!

Comment: @LucianoInfanti the difference between 75 and 120 is bigger than the difference between 200 and 300. So no not a huge difference. Depends on your print size too, for example most outoor commercials are 150